# Use RegEx to redirect using data from files

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Recently, we restructured a large site of one of our customers. This caused all the news-articels on that site to be on a different place. Problem is that the google cache is still showing them on the old location, leading to A LOT of 404 not founds ( its about 1400 news entries ).

Normally, a redirect using somewhat simple regex would be fine, but not only the path to the news did change, but also some parameters. Example:

Old Url:

```
http://www.customers-url.com/old/path/to/the/news/details/?tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=67&cHash=a782f3027c4d00face6df122a76c38ed
```

How the new url should look like:

```
http://www.customers-url.com/new/path/to/news/?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=65
```

As you can see, the parameter `D` did change from 67 to 65 and the part of the URL before the `?` did also change. Also, `tx_ttnews` has changed to `tx_news` and `tt_news` changed to `news` and the `&cHash` part did fall away completely.

I have the changed ids in a csv in the following format:

```
old_id, new_id
1,2
2,3
...etc...
```

Same goes the the changed url part before the `?`. Since im not exactly an expert in using regex my question is:

Can this be done inside the .htaccess using RegEx ( not sure if it can even use a file as input)? How complicated is that? And how would such a regular expression look like?

Comment: You will be *much* better off making a page that responds at the url `/old/path/to/the/news/details` which can use your table to look up the new id, create the new url in code, and then issue a 301 programmatically.

Comment: So you have a new path (one constant value changes to another constant), and you want to adjust the query-string. I have a hunch this might be too much for `htaccess` - I would tend to keep the old path alive and have that program just do the neccessary adjustments of the query-string and then issue a redirect to the new path with the new query-string.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I was worried it might be to much to do inside the .htaccess. I'm probably going to do it by crafting a redirect list in a python script that can be pasted into the htaccess. I think you can post you comment as an answer @ChrisLear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to use .htaccess, it would be easier to manage and easier to code if you simply make a new page that responds on the old url (`/old/path/to/the/news/details`), then make that page build the new url and return a 301 to the browser with that new url.